# how to convert Timestamp in milliseconds to javascript ? (in React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp-with-timezone

Consider code below,

```
const appointments = [

  {
    // id: 0,
  title: 'Watercolor Landscape',
  users_id: 2,
    startDate: new Date(1584576000000 * 1000),   // here is timestamps in milliseconds 
    endDate:  new Date(1584662400000* 1000),       // here is timestamps in milliseconds
    ownerId: 1,
  },
];
```

but the output of startDate was wrong, :

[image]

It should be:

startDate: Thursday, March 19, 2020 8:00:00 AM GMT+08:00

endDate:  Friday, March 20, 2020 8:00:00 AM GMT+08:00

Comment: Remove `* 1000`.

Comment: `1584576000000` is already in milliseconds. You're actually just making 1000 times more milliseconds than before.

Comment: Remove *1000. Try using moments library, there are many formats available. [https://momentjs.com]

Comment: There is no need to multiply with 1000. It is already in milliseconds

Comment: @AnglesvarCheenu no need. This is a problem with how the code is written, not a problem with how it's interpreted by the Date object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please simply use: `new Date(your_timestamps)` 
So in your code: `startDate: new Date(1584576000000)`

Read more about Date object in Javascript here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

unix timestamp is already in milliseconds, `Date.now()` gets timestamp in milliseconds!

to get unix timestamp in **seconds** you need to divide it in 1000

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a timestamp in milliseconds in JS you can do:

```
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = date.getTime();
```

If you don't intend to support IE8 or previous versions you can use:

```
Date.now();
```

**NOTE:** A timestamp is the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970.

Read more [here](https://www.toptal.com/software/definitive-guide-to-datetime-manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you just should remove `* 1000` and everything will work fine:

```
console.log(new Date(1584576000000))
// Thu Mar 19 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200

console.log(new Date(1584662400000))
// Fri Mar 20 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200
```